# Injecting a view scoped bean into another view scoped bean

Tags: jsf, managed-bean, jsf-2.2

A view scoped bean remains alive as long as the user interacts with the same view (or until it is navigated to a different view).

Suppose a view scoped managed bean is injected into another view scoped bean like so,

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public final class SharableManagedBean implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EJB
    private SharableBean sharableService;

    //...Do something.
}

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public final class TestManagedBean implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EJB
    private TestBean testBean;

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{sharableManagedBean}")
    private SharableManagedBean sharableManagedBean ;

    //... Do something with the injected bean.
}
```

In this case, is it necessary for the `SharableManagedBean` to have a view scoped bean?

What happens, if it is a request scoped bean (`SharableManagedBean`)? Is it initialized only once, when `TestManagedBean` comes into picture and destroyed, when `TestManagedBean` is destroyed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even it's technically possible to do that (**JSF allows you to inject beans which are at the same or wider scope**) I don't see the point of doing that with `@ViewScoped` beans. From my point of view, a well designed JSF web application should have a single `@ViewScoped` bean tied to each specific view. Then, how to solve your issue? You can do it in two ways:

1. If `SharableManagedBean` is a utility bean which contain static methods which are not tied to JSF, just define this class as `abstract` and statically invoke its methods everytime you need.
2. If `SharableManagedBean` itself has to be a managed bean which access the [`FacesContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html) and has common code that is shared along all the view beans, just create an `abstract` class and make your `@ViewScoped` beans extend it.

For your last question (`SharableManagedBean` being `@RequestScoped`), JSF doesn't allow you doing that. You'll get an exception because of trying to inject a narrower scoped managed bean.

According to the [Oracle docs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/index-101145.html):

> Another important point about managed beans referencing each other is that a managed bean can only refer to other beans provide their scope is equal or has a longer lifespan than the calling object.

*Update*

**If using CDI**, it's possible to inject a `@RequestScoped` bean into a `@ViewScoped` one too, using the Proxy pattern. Have [it a look](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28797562/1199132).

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks :). (I do not have votes today. Will do it right tomorrow.)

Comment: Injecting a request scoped bean in a view scoped one works when you're managing the beans by CDI. You only need to keep in mind that this actually injects a proxy which gives you the *current* instance back in method calls and it's thus not necessarily the same instance during both the postconstruct and the subsequent form submit (so, you'd need to manually copy the necessary properties in postconstruct, if any)

Comment: Didn't know that actually. I don't use CDI, so I'll need to take it a look ;-)