# CDI beans injection

Tags: jsf, cdi, jsf-2.2, managed-bean

Is this a correct approach to inject `@ApplicationScoped` bean in `@SessionScoped` bean? will this lead my application scoped bean to be stored in the session of every user?

I have an application scoped bean that contains some values we share among all the system users, and now I need to get that values within a method in a session bean.

Comment: Your question is quite vague. Can you illustrate exactly what you want to do? Besides, its quite safe to inject application-scoped beans into session beans, and vice-versa.

Comment: Hello Maress,
you already answered my question that its quite safe to inject application scopped int session beans. I will appriciate if you answer this question and will mark this answered but I will be very grateful if you give more explanation why its safe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Injecting a bean of the same or a broader scope in another bean is completely legal and correct either in JSF or CDI beans, like the example you provided.

The difference between CDI beans and JSF managed beans regarding that is when you try to inject a bean of a narrower scope in another bean (e.g inject `@RequestScoped` bean into `@SessionScoped` one), which is only possible as long as you are using CDI `@Named` beans, while not possible when working with JSF `@ManagedBean`.

The reason why this is possible for CDI beans is related to their [Proxy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) mechanism, which is more flexible compared with the JSF mechanism (based on invoking the setters in order to directly inject a physical instance).

This proxy mechanism, allow the CDI container to pass a reference to a proxy instead of the injected bean (unless a bean has the default scope `@Dependent`). Therfore, that proxy will be responsbale of handling all calls to the injected bean and forward / redirect them to the correct bean instance.

### See also:

- [CDI: Contexts and Dependency Injection for the Java EE platform - Client proxies](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/injection.html#_client_proxies)
- [Java EE 6 @javax.annotation.ManagedBean vs. @javax.inject.Named vs. @javax.faces.ManagedBean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986847/java-ee-6-javax-annotation-managedbean-vs-javax-inject-named-vs-javax-faces/12012663#12012663)
- [Backing beans (@ManagedBean) or CDI Beans (@Named)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347374/backing-beans-managedbean-or-cdi-beans-named/4347707#4347707)
- [ManagedProperty in CDI @Named bean returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9921324/managedproperty-in-cdi-named-bean-returns-null)

Comment: It's just possible in JSF, too. Only the other way round (injecting a session scoped bean in an application scoped bean) is not possible in JSF managed beans. It's indeed for precisely the proxy pattern reason only possible in CDI.

Comment: @BalusC what happened is that i was thinking the opposite while answering (that he is injecting a narrower scoped bean). Thanks for your guidance

Comment: Hi, If, for example, i inject a *VS bean(ViewScoped)* in a *ApplicationScoped bean* and there is more than one *VS bean*, **1-** Which one will be injected? **2-** Is there a situation where there is no *VS bean* to inject? if so, What will happen?